# Can I implement Html-Code as Css-Content?

Tags: php, html, css

How can I get the variable `$text` displayed as HTML?

See the code example below:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/css');
  $background = "#ffafff";
  $color = "#000000";
  $green = "#16a86f";
  $text= '<h1>TestText</h1>';
?>
body {
  background-color: <?=$background?>;
}
#logo::before{content: "<?php echo($text);?>";}
#logo {
  color: <?=$green?>;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#slogan {
   color: <?=$color?>;
}
#rahmen {
  border: 0.1em solid <?=$green?>;
  text-align: center;
}
```

At the moment I get this output:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, are you asking how to display the variable `$text` ?

Comment: You can't output html in css `content`!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have HTML Tags inside `content`:

```
$text = '<h1>TestText</h1>';
```

So, change it to just have `TestText` and then style the element with CSS to match the styles of `h1`.

```css
#logo::before {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```